# finding mean between array entries

Tags: python, numpy

Simple question:

```
bins = np.logspace(np.log10(np.amin(lightcurve)),np.log10(np.amax(lightcurve)),10) ## should work with every possible (n,1) array.
for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    bins_mean.append((bins[i+1]-bins[i])/2 +bins[i])
```

How can I speed this up? How do I address every i+1-th and every i-th element in one sweep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice with one-off shifted versions and thus compute the output in a vectorized manner -

```
bins_mean = (bins[1:]-bins[:-1])/2 +bins[:-1]
```